# Select option with cheerio (jquery) by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to select an option from a select dropdown with the `text()` attribute of the HTML element with `cheerio`. So far what I'm doing is that I'm trying to set the `attr` as selected matching, the element with the specific text.

This is what I'm trying:

```
$('#ddl_city option[text="testing"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I'm not getting any changes on the html when I do this. I print the html document on the console after doing this operation and I don't see that the option has changed to the one I'm selecting. Any idea why is not working or another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:contains` filter to get the specific `option` element based on the text and set the value of the `select` element to it's value:

```js
$('#s1').val($("#s1 option:contains('Val B')").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option value="a">Val A</option>
  <option value="b">Val B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('#ddl_city option').
    filter(function () { return $(this).text() == 'testing'; }).
    attr('selected', true);
```

Credits to Godsbest's answer in [this post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-selected-option-in-dropdownlist-by-the-text-not-value) on the jQuery forum.